# Database not accessed and no output in c#

Tags: c#

The first 2 are function in a class and second is a code.Here i have one text box i.e txtlicense  and combobox cboaccident type and combobox consists 2 selecting item i.e Death and Major.Now if i input licensenumber in txtlicense and select Death option from combobox which are present in data base it shows the ouput as per required , but problem is that if i input the licensenumber in textbox and select major option from combobox which are already present in database and press the button it didn't show any ouptput for major option.

```
public DataTable Checkdeathaccident(string LicenseNumber, string PhysicalStatus)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Integrated Security=True; Initial Catalog=tprojectDB;");
    string sql = "select DeathNumber,ReportNumber,Date from tblAccident  where LicenseNumber=@LicenseNumber and PhysicalStatus=@PhysicalStatus";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LicenseNumber", LicenseNumber);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhysicalStatus", PhysicalStatus);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    DataTable dan = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dan);
    return dan;
}

public DataTable Checkmajoraccident(string LicenseNumber, string PhysicalStatus)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Integrated Security=True; Initial Catalog=tprojectDB;");
    string sql = "select DeathNumber,ReportNumber,Date from tblAccident where LicenseNumber=@LicenseNumber and PhysicalStatus=@PhysicalStatus";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LicenseNumber", LicenseNumber);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhysicalStatus", PhysicalStatus);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    DataTable dl = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dl);
    return dl;
}    

private void button10_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dan = pac.Checkdeathaccident(txtlicense.Text, cboaccidentype.Text);
    if (dan.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        if (cboaccidentype.Text == "Death")
        {
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dan;

        }
        else
        {
           DataTable dl = pac.Checkmajoraccident(txtlicense.Text, cboaccidentype.Text);
            if (dl.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if (cboaccidentype.Text == "Major")
                {

                    dataGridView2.DataSource = dl;

                }                               
            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No Record Found");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are `Checkdeathaccident` and `Checkmajoraccident` identical functions?

Answer (score 1):

As Paul mentioned you have the same functions running to fill the same gridview with the same select query, you could refactor to this and it should work, I didn't test this just an idea.

```
public DataTable checkAccident(string LicenseNumber, string PhysicalStatus)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Integrated Security=True; Initial Catalog=tprojectDB;");
    string sql = "select DeathNumber,ReportNumber,Date from tblAccident where LicenseNumber=@LicenseNumber and PhysicalStatus=@PhysicalStatus";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LicenseNumber", LicenseNumber);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhysicalStatus", PhysicalStatus);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    DataTable dl = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dl);
    return dl;
}    

private void button10_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dan = pac.checkAccident(txtlicense.Text, cboaccidentype.Text);
    if (dan.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dan;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No Record Found");
    }
}
```